# python HTML custom tag in scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im trying to remove the info from the data-ldpemail tag only and not the entire a tag.

any ideas on how i can do this using python and beautiful soup.. i keep getting the entire a tag not just that 'data-ldpemail'.
Below is the sample tag:

`<a class="lf_font-weight--light agent-email mailto" data-ldpphone="111-111-111" data-ldpemail="person@company.com" data-personid="10480733">Me</a>`

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('test.html'), 'html.parser') 
people = soup.find('div', id='search-results') 
items = people.find_all('figure') 
#print(items) 
print(items[0].find('h1').get_text())
print(items[0].find('h3').get_text()) 
email = soup.find('a', attrs={"data-ldpemail" : "x"}) 
email = email.attrs['data-ldpemail'] 
print(email)
```

Comment: Hi! Could you edit your post to include the code you're using that returns "the entire a tag"? Just the relevant line would suffice.

Comment: import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('test.html'), 'html.parser')
people = soup.find('div', id='search-results')

items = people.find_all('figure')
#print(items)


print(items[0].find('h1').get_text())
print(items[0].find('h3').get_text())

email = soup.find('a', attrs={"data-ldpemail" : "x"})
mail = email.attrs['data-ldpemail']
print(email)


So this is where i am, the figure is within a div, of multiples of these elements. i have not yet created the name and email section yet, still trying to get it pull that information, before a loop

Comment: Just a heads up, the line in your code `email = soup.find('a', attrs={"data-ldpemail": "x"})` Isn't going to return anything unless there is some tag where "data-ldpemail" is exactly equal to the string "x"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any code to demonstrate how you got to where you are I am assuming you know how to isolate the "a" tags you want.

It is important to note that in the example "data-ldpemail" is not a tag but a tag attribute for the "a" (anchor) tag. Suppose you have an a tag isolated which has that attribute then to extract the value of that attribute:

```py
a_tag.attrs['data-ldpemail']
```

`bs4.element.Tag.attrs` will return a dictionary containing all the attributes of the tag as keys, with the value of each tag as the dictionary value. Then we just access that key of the attribute dictionary.

one line to grab all from some soup:

```py
email_list = [tag.attrs.get('data-ldpemail') for tag in soup.find_all('a') if tag.attrs.get('data-ldpemail') is not None]
```

What the one liner above does is find all of the anchor tags in the entire soup object, iterates through that set, adding the value of 'data-ldpemail' tag attribute to the `email_list` if that anchor tag has the 'data-ldpemail' attribute.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  it has solved my entire issue.